# Pasar datos obtenido en un script a una controladora

Tags: ajax, script, symfony4

Tengo una vista donde los datosa llenar están en forma de tabla, pero no es un formulario creado en el controlador sino en la propia vista aunque tampoco tiene la etiqueta form.
Los input son creados automáticamente según la cantidad de países con los que se tenga relación.

```
            {% for paisDestino in paisesDestino %}
                {% set sizePaisesDest = loop.index %}
            <tr>
                <td>Transpondedor RFID pasivo CU a {{ paisDestino.codigo }}</td>
                {% for arrTotalesPais in arrTotalesPaises %}
                    {% if loop.index == sizePaisesDest %}
                        <td>{{ arrTotalesPais }}</td>
                        <td> Del <input type="text" maxlength="17" minlength="17" name="ti[]">
                            al <input type="text" maxlength="17" minlength="17" name="tf[]"></td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

En un script recojo la información que introduce el usuario y con ajax trato de hacer esa conexión pero no me funciona.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function obtenerValores() {
            var transpondedoresIniciales = document.getElementsByName("ti[]");
            $.ajax({
                url : {{ path('materiales_corresponsal', {
                    'corresponsal':'corresponsal'
                }) }},
            })
    </script>
```

Y la controladora

```
   /**
    * @Route("/introducir", name="materiales_corresponsal")
    */
   public function introducirMateriales($corresponsalCodigo): Response
   {
       echo $corresponsalCodigo;
   }
```

En esta función solo hago un echo para probar, en realidad el objetivo de esta función es guardar la información en la BD